# Summary Links Web part

Tags: web-part, list-view, datasheet, links-list

Got about 60 links to add to a custom sharepoint, and I am going to use a summary link web part with an 'accordion style' like Stefan Bauer created. Adding a few are not a problem - but this is 60 lol.

I have the links in excel with column A with the link title and column b the actual URL. Is there a quicker way to incorporate these 60 links through designer maybe or pull from a list view? (something where i can mass add up front - then update as URLs change, new ones are added individually etc).

http://www.n8d.at/blog/turn-summary-link-web-part-into-an-accordion/

Answer (score 2):

The Summary links web part is a static web part, meaning that all links are manually entered and maintained. A much flexibile approach, which will allow you in the future to control the content outside of the web part would be to import the Excel file into a new Links list by example and use the Data View web part to create the Accordion.

Please consult the following resources

- http://sympmarc.com/2011/11/02/creating-a-jquery-accordion-with-a-data-view-web-part/
- http://blog.slalom.com/2011/02/16/accordion-data-view-web-part/
- http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=158